# Passing data as array - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing data and file as an array to my API.

But at the API level, I do a check to see if the recipient is in array format.

In my code, I am passing my data as an array but the API returns an error that my data isn't in array form.

What could I be doing wrong here please ?

**Error**

> > Make sure you are returning destination field as an array

**Client Side**

```
if(function_exists('curl_file_create'))
{
    $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
} else {
    $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);  
}

$post = array( 'destination' => ['00448923202'], 'file'=>$cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
return $result;
curl_close ($ch);
```

**API Level**

```
$destination = $request->post('destination');

if (!is_array($destination)) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Make sure you are passing the destination field as an array'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `curl_close ($ch);` will never execute since it happens after the `return` - just a point to note.

Comment: You encode the data when sending it, you have to decode it when receiving. Try: json_decode()

Comment: Guess you need to decode your JSON on API level??

Comment: Why do you send `destination` to your backend, but check for `recipient`?

Comment: @NicoHaase, i mixed up my variables but updated.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, thank you.. typo fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you take `recipient` from because it's not in the request you show. Seems like you mixed some variables.

Second, you are missing the `json_decode()` because you are sending JSON, you need to decode it after receiving.

Concerning the functions you are looking for `array_key_exists()` or simply `isset()`.

Example:

```
$test = ['destination' => '12345'];

var_dump(isset($test['destination']));
var_dump(array_key_exists('destination', $test));
```

Comment: so isset or array_key_exists() decodes json you mean ?

Comment: @CodeNewbie no, `json_decode()` decodes JSON (?!). `isset()` checks for isset and array... dude, the functions name say what they do?! Please go to php.net and read about stuff.. you didn't even try the code example,...

Comment: Your answer is basically not making any sense or meaning to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5.x, you will use `$request->get('recipient')` to get parameters, regardless if it is by `POST` or `GET` method.

Comment: Can you explain further why you think that this could solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, `$request->post('recipient')` doesn`t work. If you want to check that `Client Side` send correctly parameters, you can do `dd( $request->all() );`, if return empty data, your problem was in `Client Side`.